# Trying to access Google calendar's API but get <<FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'>> error

Tags: python, api, google-calendar-api

I want to use google calendar's API. However, I get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'credentials.json'

Here's my code at this point of time:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import requests 
import os
import datetime
import json
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
#flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets_file.json", scopes=scopes) from previous attempts
#credentials = flow.run_console()    this too

def main():
    creds=None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds=Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json',scopes)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow= InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json',scopes)
            creds=flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json','w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is from a more recent tutorial thought that may help as in some previous attempts the tutorials seemed outdated.

Comment: The error message tells you all you need to know. The file *credentials.json* doesn't exist in your current working directory

Comment: have you gone through [this](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials) to get the credentials?

Comment: Yes, I already have the .json file with the credentials

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json',scopes)
```

tries to load a 'credentials.json', which should contain the API credentials for your Google Cloud application. The file should be in the same folder than your output .exe file.

Check out the "Creating your client credentials" section [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) or the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials) for how to create credentials for your end users (which is what should be inside the credentials.json file)

Comment: I did already create a client credentials .json file initially and I renamed it to the exact same thing as in the error message but to no avail. And I don't have a .exe file I was just wanting to make a small script for myself.

Comment: Correction: "your .py file". My bad ^^

Make sure the folder you are starting the python interpreter from is the same that the credentials.json file sits in.

If you are starting the python file from an IDE/Code editor (VSCode, etc.), be aware it often starts the terminal in the root folder of your project and then uses the relative path to refer to the python file, which results in the working directory of the python interpreter to be the root folder.